# Looking for a multi-monitor wallpaper switcher

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-background

I've been looking without much success for a good Linux multi monitor wallpaper switcher.  (Doesn't mean my search technique isn't fundamentally flawed) Regardless, would appreciate any suggestions/referrals.

To provide some additional perspective, I'm mainly looking for the linux equivalent of [John's Background Switcher](http://johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this one before it pretty decent, allows you to do a couple of other things as well, workspace specific backgrounds and time elapsed changes too!

http://wallpapoz.akbarhome.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [Syncwall](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/syncwall-wallpaper-changer-with-multi.html) for my multi-monitor wallpapers.